# Advise on how to identify a mouse over effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure if this type of question allowed on Stackoverflow, but I thought I'd ask and see if anyone can share some advice.

I've tried inspecting the code for [this website](http://www.themustafacelik.com/) as I'm interested to understand what this effect is (when hovering over/moving mouse over the background image) and how it's created. I'm not having much luck so wondered if anyone can point me in the right direction so I can figure it out, I'd like to recreate it.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Checkout the DOM with the inspector and you will see that's implemented using a [canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp).

Comment: If you inspect the website you can find that it uses [pixiJS](https://www.pixijs.com/gallery). Snippet of the code can be found in the function `pixi_home` in [main.js](http://www.themustafacelik.com/wp-content/themes/mustafa/dev/main.js)

Comment: It's a <canvas> element, effect is controlled via js

Comment: And none of the used libraries has the required license note included...

Comment: Thanks all for the advise I really appreciate you all taking time to take a look at this for me!